# How to get replies to messages

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telegram-bot, pyrogram

I am using pyrogram, I need to retrieve responses from a message, knowing that it has been replied to
[image: telegram example]

I tried `MessageReplies` and `messages.GetReplies` but nothing worked

```py
@user1.on_message(filters.group)
async def replies(client, message):
    try:
        if "?" in message.text:
            async for find in user1.search_messages(message.chat.id, query=message.text, limit=2):
                print(find)
                GetReplies()
```

Comment: post the code and not the pictures of code.
Users need to be able to replicate the problem quickly, 
which text allows for (and pictures do not).
[how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)